# Using multiple different forms on one page (Crispyforms in Django 1.7)

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms, django-1.7

I am trying to show a number of forms on one page for my University management website. The idea is that it should be possible for a teacher to enter all marks for a group in a group assessment on the same page. The view should display a group element form and then a number of forms for the individual elements (the size of the group can vary).

The Django documentation is a bit short about the idea of form prefixes, so I'm not quite sure if that's the right approach. I would like to render the forms with crispy forms. Is this approach going to work or is there a better way to achieve the aim I have in mind?

```
views.py
--------
# Generate the forms for the template
group_form = GroupForm(prefix='group')
student_forms = []
for student in students_in_group:
    student_form = StudentForm(initial={...}, prefix=student.student_id)
    student_forms.append(student_form)
...
# Processing post request
if request.method == 'POST':
    group_form = GroupForm(request.POST, prefix='group')
    if group_form.is_valid():
        group_form.save()
    for student in students_in_group:
        student_form = StudentForm(request.POST, prefix=student.student_id)
        if student_form.is_valid():
            student_form.save()


group_feedback.html
-------------------
{% crispy group_form %}
{% for form in student_forms %}
{% crispy form %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code does appear like it should function the way you are expecting.  Although, it may be a cleaner approach to use a formset for the list of `StudentForm` forms.

## views.py

```
StudentFormSet = modelformset_factory(Student)

# Processing post request
if request.method == 'POST':
    group_form = GroupForm(request.POST, prefix='group')
    if group_form.is_valid():
        group_form.save()
    formset = StudentFormSet(request.POST, prefix='student')
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
else:
    # Generate the forms for the template
    group_form = GroupForm(prefix='group')
    formset = StudentFormSet(queryset=Student.objects.filter(whatever gives you students_in_group), prefix='student')
```

I haven't vetted how formsets would play with crispyforms for what it's worth.